# I am trying to find all the element that have the tag "typedef" in certain xml files using python library elementtree but it gives me an empty array

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Here is my code:

```
       for file in os.listdir('YinFiles'):
            file = os.path.join('YinFiles',file)
            tree = ET.parse(file)
            all_typedef_elements = tree.findall('.//typedef')
    
        print(all_typedef_elements)
```

but it is giving me an empty array

Comment: You are only printing the result for the final file. Could it be that particular one that does not contain any `typedef` element? What happens when you move the print statement inside your for-loop?

Comment: It is much easier to help if you provide a proper [mcve], including a sample XML file. This could for example be related to XML namespaces, but we cannot tell.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the fact that you print `all_typedef_elements` only once at the end (after the `for` loop). If you only need to print all the lists, you could to it like this:

```py
for file in os.listdir('YinFiles'):
    file = os.path.join('YinFiles',file)
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    all_typedef_elements = tree.findall('.//typedef')
    
    print(all_typedef_elements) # this line is indented now
```

However, if you need all the results in a single list at the end, you could do something like this:

```py
all_typedef_elements = []

for file in os.listdir('YinFiles'):
    file = os.path.join('YinFiles',file)
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    file_typedef_elements = tree.findall('.//typedef')
    all_typedef_elements += file_typedef_elements

print(all_typedef_elements)
```

Comment: Oh thanks a lot , it was a mistake yes. But the problem still exists even when I corrected the code. Probably something else is also wrong.. :/

Comment: Probably, but to further investigate the issue you need to provide an example of file you are working with.